# Reference / bibliography management in Emacs: helm-bibtex, org-ref, ebib

Tags: emacs, bibliography

To manage your bibliography and in-text citations, which tools are best to use in Emacs? I am pretty confused about for instance helm-bibtex, org-ref, and ebib. Are these different packages for the samae thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`org-ref`: a reference management system that integrates tightly with `org-mode`. I think of it like a lightweight Zotero but fully inside emacs (eg you can edit bibtex files, insert citations, search/download PDFs for references, insert bibliographies, etc). The youtube video on the Github page does a pretty good job explaining what it does and its intended workflow.

`helm-bibtex`: a search tool for `.bib` files. Execute `helm-bibtex` and it presents a list of whatever `.bib` files you configure it to search. When you 'select' something you have the option of navigating to the URL, opening the PDF, inserting the entry as a citation, inserting the BibTeX entry, etc. Also there is another command called `ivy-bibtex` which is confusingly part of the `helm-bibtex` package which does the same thing but with `ivy`. Furthermore, `org-ref` depends on `helm-bibtex` so consider the features of the latter to be a subset of the former.

`ebib`: as far as I can tell this is separate from the other two but looks like it overlaps with `org-ref` (or at least it has the ability to download PDFs, insert citations, follow URLs, search `.bib` files, etc). The main difference is that it appears the intention for `ebib` is to provide a nice tool for editing `.bib` files themselves, although it can do more than just that.

FWIW I personally use Zotero for managing my `.bib` files and then search/insert from them with `ivy-bibtex/helm-bibtex` when writing. I have `ebib` and `org-ref` half-configured but I never really needed to use them given that Zotero makes up for alot of the features that don't directly involve writing a manuscript. I also prefer to write in straight LaTeX rather than use `org-mode`'s export functionality (just personal preferences), so this also removes the incentive for me to use `org-ref` since it seems geared toward writing in `org-mode` itself.

You can obviously do whatever you want just using Emacs packages and not rely on Zotero at all, but that should give a sense of what functionality each package provides.

Comment: Thank you so much. So the part that creates in-text citations and displays bibliography lists in whichever style (Chicago, Apa, etc.) is not helm-Bibtex but org-ref, as org-ref is the proper reference manager and helm-bibtex just the search engine? Can you confirm this? Thanks for this. As you see, sometimes it becomes hard to establish your own workflow when there are so many tools intended for the same purpose.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein short answer yes, long answer is that org-ref has its own way of handling bibliography styles where you enter `bibliographystyle:unsrt` rather than `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` (and similar for citations and figure references). I haven't looked at the code enough to see how robust/comprehensive this is but it uses its own style definition files written in lisp rather than `.bst` files (which are a pain to hack in my experience). If you don't want to use org-ref you can also just use the `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in org itself with the built-in LaTeX exporter.

Comment: Thank you! Exctly how would I use "bibliographystyle:unsrt" for CHICAGO style?

Comment: `bibliographystyle:chicago`? `unsrt` is just another style (unsorted)

Comment: Until today I was a Zotero user, but I really like the potential of Ebib and unfortunately that does not work well with Zotero. But today I have discovered that JabRef stores/manages its database as .bib file. And besides that, its browser extension is usable without a JabRef instance running. So Jabref seems to be a much better match with Emacs (at least for me). So I have simply exported my Zotero database, including the files, and now I am using the new .bib file as the JabRef database. Now I only have to fix the by Zotero exported bibtex file keyword paths, but should be easy with Emacs.

Comment: On the other hand if you rely on the Zotero web-api then you might prefer to use that in combination with the [Emacs Zotero package](https://gitlab.com/fvdbeek/emacs-zotero).